# When is an AR(1) process strictly stationary?

Tags: stationarity, autoregressive, joint-distribution

Suppose I have an AR(1) process $X_t=aX_{t-1}+e_t$, where $e_t$ is a white noise with zero mean and finite variance. Under what conditions do I have $\{X_t\}$ being strictly stationary
in the sense that the joint distribution of $[X_{t_1},...,X_{t_k}]$ and $[X_{t_1+a},...,X_{t_k+a}]$ are the same for any set of integers $t_1,...,t_k$ and any integer $a$?

Comment: A implicit assumption seems to be that $e_t$ is independent of the r.vs $X_s$ for $s \leq t-1$?

Comment: @Yves Thanks! Do you mean the independence between $e_t$ and past $X_s$ suffices for strict stationarity? or do you mean this independence assumption is usually maintained for an AR(1) model, regardless of its stationarity?

Comment: Without independence I believe that you do not specify the distribution of the process $X_t$.

Comment: I think independence assumption is usually maintained for an AR(1) model, regardless of its stationarity.

Comment: Should it not be a sufficient condition that the variance is stationary, $|a|<1$?

Comment: Also the question seems to be about the *existence of a stationary solution* of the stochastic difference equation. Indeed the equation must be completed by some initial condition to specify the distribution of the process $X_t$.

Comment: @RichardHardy Agree.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I think this is only sufficient for weak stationarity.

Comment: @Yves Now I see it. Initial condition must be specified. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume that the definition of the AR(1) process includes a specification of $X_0$ (absent which $X_1 = aX_0+ \varepsilon_1$ is difficult to interpret).

The simplest choice is $X_0 = 0$ which makes
\begin{array}
{}X_1 &= \varepsilon_1\\
X_2 &=  \varepsilon_2 + a\varepsilon_1\\
X_3 &= \varepsilon_3 + a\varepsilon_2 + a^2\varepsilon_1\\
\vdots &= \ddots
\end{array}
For the process to be *strictly stationary*, it is necessary that $X_1$ and $X_2$ be identically distributed. But, since $\varepsilon_t$ is a white noise process, we have that
\begin{array}
{}\operatorname{var}(X_1) &= \sigma^2\\
{}\operatorname{var}(X_2) &= \operatorname{var}(\varepsilon_2) +a^2 \operatorname{var}(\varepsilon_1) + 2a\operatorname{cov}(\varepsilon_2,\varepsilon_1)\\
&= \sigma^2 + a^2 \sigma^2 + 0\\
&= \sigma^2(1 + a^2)\\
&\neq \sigma^2 = \operatorname{var}(X_1)
\end{array}
and so the process cannot possibly be a strictly stationary process.

**If** $|a| < 1,$ then the variance of $X_n$ converges to $\dfrac{\sigma^2}{1-a^2}$. So, what happens if we set $X_0$ to have variance $\dfrac{\sigma^2}{1-a^2}$ and to be independent of the white noise process? Well, then
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(X_1) &= \dfrac{a^2\sigma^2}{1-a^2}+ \sigma^2\\
&= \dfrac{\sigma^2}{1-a^2}\\
&= \operatorname{var}(X_0).
\end{align}
Inductively, we get that *all* the $X_i$ have the same variance $\dfrac{\sigma^2}{1-a^2}$.  However, equality of variances is *not* the same as equality of distributions, and there is no guarantee that the process is stationary even to order $1$, let alone be *strictly stationary.*.  I will leave it as an exercise for the OP to determine whether this process is a *weakly stationary* process (also called wide-sense-stationary process, or, in the time-series literature, stationary process).

Finally, if the white noise process is a *Gaussian* white noise process (which requires, among other things, that all the random variables are *jointly* Gaussian), then for $|a|< 1$, and $X_0 \sim N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{1-a^2}\right)$, the process
$\left\{X_n\colon n \geq 0\right\}$ **is** a *strictly stationary* (Gaussian) process.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful.